# Append to string in C

Tags: c, string

So I have a string which will have the following rough format: `string # more than one string here`.

What I want to do is strip everything after the `#`. How would I do that? Furthermore, what if I just want to keep the initial string, and take everything after the space and the `#`?

I have the following code, but obviously appending something to a `NULL` string does not work as expected:

`char *inst_ptr` holds the whole string.

```
char *lbl = NULL;
int len = 0;
size_t inst_len = strlen(inst_ptr);
for (int t = 0; t < inst_len; t++) {

    if (inst_ptr[t] == '#')
        break;

    else {
        printf("len %d\n", len);
        lbl[len] = inst_ptr[t];
        lbl[len+1] = '\0';
        len = strlen(lbl);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Basically, assume I have the following string:
`loop # hello world!`

I just want to extract `loop` in another string. What I am doing above is having `lbl` as a NULL string, and run a loop across the original string. As long as the character is not `#`, i just "append" the character with a  null terminator as shown above.

Comment: I think you meant *strip* instead of *strap*, and *take out* (or *remove*) instead of *take*.

Comment: I don't understand your use of "append" word. What should be the result for the `string # more than one string` you mention? Do you want to get just `string #`?

Comment: `lbl` is `null`, so `lbl[len]` will get you segfault. You'll need to: 1) find length of substring you want to get; 2) allocate that amount of `char`s (don't forget to check for empty substring here) 3) `memcpy` substring from original place to allocated memory. 4) don't forget to call `free` on memory allocated for substring when you done. Or you'll get memory leak :)

Comment: @VictorSorokin I am trying to do it in one loop. Your solution requires two loops. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are doing

```
char *lbl = NULL;
```

Then you are doing

```
lbl[len]
```

You're trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer and causing undefined behaviour.

First, you need to allocate memory for that string (`calloc` allocates the memory and sets it all to `0`, which will obviate the need to manually add the null terminator):

```
char *lbl = calloc(inst_len + 1, 1);
```

Then you need to fix your loop, some of the things are in the wrong place. It should be

```
for (int t = 0; t < inst_len; t++) {
    if (inst_ptr[t] == '#') {
        len = t - 1; // strlen(lbl) is redundant
        break;
    } else
        lbl[t] = inst_ptr[t];
}
```

Then when you are done, `free` the memory you allocated so as not to cause a memory leak:

```
free(lbl);
```

Comment: Does not work. `calloc` takes the size of the element too. Would that be `sizeof(char)`? So: `char *lbl = calloc(inst_len + 1, sizeof(char));`?

Comment: sizeof(char) is defined to be 1 in a C89 compliant environment, but otherwise you're correct

Comment: Thanks. I did that and it did not work. `lbl` prints out as an empty string so @SethCarnegie's code is wrong.

Comment: Recall that sizeof(char) is *always* 1. Yes, the calloc( ) calling sequence takes nmemb and sizeof(memb) so: lbl = calloc ( nmemb, 1 );

Comment: @Nayefc sorry, I wrote this answer and had to leave. I see the problem now, I had copied `lbl[len] = inst_ptr[t];` from your code and forgot to change it to `lbl[t] = inst_ptr[t];`. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should check section 7.21 in [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for some inspiration.

The best approach depends on the rest of your application. 
If you don't care about the original data, you could just use

```
strtok(inst_ptr, "#");
```

Or it might be better to allocate-and-copy just the data you need:

```
char * temp = strchr(inst_ptr, '#');
char * lbl;

if (temp)
   lbl = strndup(inst_ptr, temp - inst_ptr);
else
   lbl = strdup(inst_ptr);
```

Please note that the above are the minimal implemenations I've come to think of off the top of my head, not necessarily the best ones.